# Change box color randomly when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change color of box randomly when button is clicked. But when I click on  button background becomes white. I dont know the reason i am color flipper project and got stuck here. I checked console their color values are generating but it is not getting assigned to background-color: property.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

function Box() {
    function randomRGB(){
        // console.log("random");
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    }
    function getRandomColor() {
        const color ='rgb(' + randomRGB() + ',' + randomRGB() + ',' + randomRGB() + ')';
        console.log(color);
        return color;
    }
    var [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState(getRandomColor());
  return (
    <div>
        <BoxC back={currentColor}></BoxC>
        <Div onClick={setCurrentColor}>Button</Div>
    </div>
  )
}
var BoxC = styled.div`
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: ${(props) => props.back};
`
const Div = styled.button`
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    cursor: pointer;
`
export default Box
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to assign a new color on click by

```
onClick={()=>setCurrentColor(randomrgb())}>Button</Div>
```

Comment: Not good this way. What if he/she needs to reuse the function somewhere else? Best to call the update state function inside the getRandomColor function

Comment: Updated . The getter function is completely useless

Answer (score -1):

You are not setting the currentColor state to anything. You are just calling the function.

Do it like this instead:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

function Box() {
var [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState(getRandomColor());
    function randomRGB(){
        // console.log("random");
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    }
    function getRandomColor() {
        const color ='rgb(' + randomRGB() + ',' + randomRGB() + ',' + randomRGB() + ')';
        console.log(color);
        return setCurrentColor(color);
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <BoxC back={currentColor}></BoxC>
        <Div onClick={() => getRandomColor()}>Button</Div>
    </div>
  )
}
var BoxC = styled.div`
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: ${(props) => props.back};
`
const Div = styled.button`
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    cursor: pointer;
`
export default Box
```

Comment: Not a good practice to set a state in a getter

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann and why is that?? Can you explain?

Comment: It's best to do it this way for re-usability. That's the whole point of react.

Comment: It's about the naming. In state init you don't want to have a void function and when updating state the method used should reflect this in it's function name. Nobody would assume you are updating state by calling getsomething.

Comment: That could easily be changed. That's no reason to mark down my answer. He could change the func name to something appropriate to the function actions. Setting the state inside the function should be best for reusability. He might need to call the function somewhere else and shouldn't have to repeat code to update the color

Comment: Il will upvote if the code follows "clean code" practices

Comment: I can recommend the book "clean code" by Robert c martin